# Help with Nexus 6P bootloop: Couldn't parse partition size '0x' when trying to flash new image

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, bootloader, nexus-6p

I need help with my Nexus 6P.

Because of a bootloop, I was trying to flash a new boot image. I went to the Google download page for factory images and tried using the "flash-all.bat" file. I don't know how to exactly explain this but, here is the full command prompt line from the flash-all batch file.

Note: It also says my device is corrupt while trying to go into recovery mode.

I don't know how to fix, please help :(

```
Sending 'bootloader' (3544 KB)                     OKAY [  0.136s]
Writing 'bootloader'                               OKAY [  0.215s]
Finished. Total time: 0.405s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.108s]
Finished. Total time: 0.113s
Sending 'radio' (48728 KB)                         OKAY [  1.511s]
Writing 'radio'                                    OKAY [  2.174s]
Finished. Total time: 3.741s
Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.007s]
Finished. Total time: 0.009s
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: angler-03.68
Baseband Version.....: angler-03.81
Serial Number........: 84B7N16109000032
--------------------------------------------
extracting android-info.txt (0 MB) to RAM...
Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [  0.018s]
Checking 'version-bootloader'                      OKAY [  0.018s]
Checking 'version-baseband'                        OKAY [  0.018s]
extracting boot.img (12 MB) to disk... took 0.033s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
fastboot: error: Couldn't parse partition size '0x'.
Press any key to exit...
```

Flashing vendor, system, and recovery individually works but boot doesn't. When flashing boot image on its own, it also says the same thing.

```
fastboot: error: Couldn't parse partition size '0x'.
```

Comment: Is the device unlocked? BTW: Even if Huawei technically is the manufacturer usually people speak about "Google Nexus 6P" because everything relevant is provided by Google.

Comment: Yes, the device is unlocked.